# Solving coupled non-linear equations

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-optimization

I am struggling to understand what the following question requires me to do:[image]

I believe I need to differentiate implicitly, but am unsure how I show it cannot be done.

Comment: the second equation can be solved for $y$

Answer (score 0):

Compute the total differentials:
$$3x^2dx+e^ydy=ds,\\-\sin xdx+y dx+x dy=dt.$$
At $(x,y)=(0,0)$,

$$0dx+dy=ds,\\0dx+0dy=dt.$$
The Jacobian matrix of the transform is singular.